# Convert RBG char array to RGB int value in Java

Tags: java

I have a `char[] rbg` containing :

- `rgb[0]` : red value
- `rgb[1]` : green value
- `rgb[2]` : blue value

I want to use the method `BufferedImage::setRGB(x, y, int rgb)`

How can I proceed to convert the char array to the int value ?

Note : I use Java

**Edit : I'm looking for the fastest solution**

Thanks

Comment: why do you have a char array? do your r,g and b components only have one digit each?

Comment: r, g and b are 8 bit, so each one is a char. This data comes from a C++ program via socket.

Comment: your requirements aren't clear: what does you char[] contain? Say for zero, does it contain 0 or the character '0'? Anyway, a Java char is 16 bit, not 8, so it's a total transmission waste here and a processing waste too (apparently speed is a concern seen your bold "*I'm looking for the fastest solution"* edit.  Fastest solution would to transmit something that makes more sense from the C++ program.

Comment: Hi, you're right I shouldn't use char but byte !! Thanks. The problem is when using byte, they are signed, so I have negative values which creates bugs. How can I have only unsigned byte ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int value = ((255 & 0xFF) << 24) | //alpha
            (((int)rgb[0] & 0xFF) << 16) | //red
            (((int)rgb[1] & 0xFF) << 8)  | //green
            (((int)rgb[2] & 0xFF) << 0); //blue
```

Comment: is the alpha channel needed ?

Comment: yes, every color has an alpha which defines its transparency. 255 means that it is completely opaque.

Comment: this answer is much faster than the first one.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.awt.Color;

Color color = new Color(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2]);
int rgb = color.getRGB();
```

ref : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB%28%29

Comment: Oh that's a "clean" solution, but is that faster than a raw calculus (like the other solutions) ?

Comment: Basically the same thing, take a look at the java.awt.Color source code (http://kickjava.com/src/java/awt/Color.java.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
int rgb2 = rgb[0] << 16 | rgb[1] << 8 | rgb[2];
```

Maybe you will have to reverse the order of indices.

Comment: Will java automatically promote `rgb[0]` to `int`? I wasn't sure.

Comment: Is that one faster than the other solutions ?

Comment: @egrunin: yes, since 16 and 8 are ints. @Matthieu: Probably. But unless speed is really important, you should use library functions (i.e. use the example of RealHowTo if you are using the BufferedImage of awt).

Comment: If you use your one code, make it a static final function. It will be inlined by the compiler and improves readability.

Answer (score -1):

```
BufferedImage buffImg = new BufferedImage(176, 144, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            /*Setting RGB values to BufferedImage*/
            int[] raw = new int[rgbCameraData.length * 4 / 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < rgbCameraData.length / 3; i++) {
                raw[i] = 0xFF000000
                        | ((rgbCameraData[3 * i + 0] & 0xFF) << 16)
                        | ((rgbCameraData[3 * i + 1] & 0xFF) << 8)
                        | ((rgbCameraData[3 * i + 2] & 0xFF));
            }
            buffImg.setRGB(0, 0, 176, 144, raw, 0, 176);
            System.out.println("BufferedImage  :" + img);
```